# Как создать папку или файл с FTP в VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ftp, sftp

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли возможность создавать файлы и папки?

Comment: а как к фтп подключаетесь? каким плагином?

Comment: http://joxi.ru/52ao3N0slb97Vr liximomo, вроде все хорошо, но вот удалять можно, а добавить папку или файл нет.

Comment: sftp это не совсем ftp. Если это заработало, значит есть доступ к серверу по ssh? а тогда можно настроить vscode в особом режиме и работать с удаленным сервером как будто с локальной машиной.